# unclear step in a logarithmic expression simplification routine (trivial question)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I don't understand why the value there is $\frac14$ and not $-\frac12$. The base of the second logarithm could be viewed as $a$ with power equaling $-1$, couldn't it? Then its multiplication by $\frac12$ should give $-\frac12$.

From my textbook's "solution volume" (the task is to simplify the expression):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$log_{1/a}^2\sqrt{a^2-1}=(log_{1/a}\sqrt{a^2-1})^2=\left(\frac{log_{a}\sqrt{a^2-1}}{log_{a}{(a^{-1})}}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\frac12log_{a}{(a^2-1)}}{-log_{a}{a}}\right)^2=\frac14\left(log_{a}{(a^2-1)}\right)^2=\frac14log_{a}^2{(a^2-1)}$$

Comment: Oh, it's one-fourth because it has been *squared*! Thank you, Joefu! I overlooked this aspect: to remember that the whole logarithm is squared.

Comment: You are welcome :0)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the change of base formula: 
$$
\log_b(x)=\dfrac{\log_a (x)}{\log_a (b)}
$$

In your case (as an example)
$$
\log_{\sqrt[3]{a}}(x)=\dfrac{\log_a (x)}{\log_a (\sqrt[3]{a})}=3\log_a (x)
$$

Comment: Thank you, Emilio, but I meant another term in the expression. Maybe I wasn't thorough enough in marking it. (0:

Comment: With the same formula you can find $\log_{1/a} x$ and $\log_{a^2} x$ in terms of $\log_{a} x$. Can you do this?

Comment: Ah, I see, you provided a hint in order for me to repeat the procedure. Yes, I can do this, thank you.

Comment: You are wellcome :)